# How to select the user's location annotation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to figure out how I would select the user's default location annotation when the map is first displayed to the user. I know I should probably be using this code somehow:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(theUsersLocationAnnotation, animated: true)
```

But where is this 'theUsersLocationAnnotation' Annotation coming from exactly since it's the current location annotation that is normally blue. How would I access this to call this on that annotation, so-to-speak?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
 mapView.selectAnnotation(mapView.userLocation, animated: true)
```